# Collation conflict when creating stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, json, collation

I'm trying to create a stored procedure but it gives me the error message
`Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_BIN2" in the EXCEPT operation.`

The thing is that both the database and server collation is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` and I have no clue where the `Latin1_General_BIN2` collation comes from.

```
create procedure [ETL_1.4.0].update_valve_event_type
(
    @data nvarchar(max)
)
as
    declare @mismatch_table table(id int, [name] varchar(50))

    if isjson(@data) = 0
    begin
        ;throw 50000,'Input argument @data is invalid JSON.', 1
    end

    insert @mismatch_table (id, [name])
    select * from
    (
        select
            value as id,
            [key] as [name]
        from openjson(@data)
        except
        select
            id,
            [name]
        from enum.valve_event
    )data

    --clear mismatches that are deemed ok, e.g. spelling corrections
    delete from @mismatch_table
    where id = 10 and [name] = 'FEEDBACK_FROM_USER'

    if exists(select * from @mismatch_table)
    begin
        ;throw 50000,'Terminal version of enum for valve events does not match the EDW version', 1
    end
go
```

So can someone explain what I'm missing?
If it matters, this database (and server for that matter) is not live yet so technically I have the ability to change collations wherever I want.

Comment: Martin: I have updated my answer to include info about which collation to force, clarify which collation is used for the `value` column of the returned table, and provide an easier method of discovering the collation of columns in the output from a table-valued function (as suggested by @Charlieface ). Please review.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is likely the output from the `OPENJSON` function, especially since that is part of an `EXCEPT` operation. All you need to do is force a collation in that query via the `COLLATE` option/keyword. For example:

```sql
...
    [key] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS as [name]
from openjson(@data)
...
```

As for which collation to force, pick one that supports how you want the operation to behave (in simple terms: should **'A' = 'a'** *or* **'A' <> 'a'**). The two most likely options are the two collations already being used: `Latin1_General_BIN2`, and (in this particular case) `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. (And yes, if you choose `Latin1_General_BIN2` which is already the collation of the `key` column, you still need to specify the `COLLATE` option, as shown above, in order to avoid the error.)

The documentation for [OPENJSON()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql) even loosely states that the output uses a `BIN2` collation (though it doesn't specify the exact collation, and I'm not going to quote it as the description isn't exactly correct).

The best option is to just ask SQL Server. We can verify the collation of the output columns by storing them in a table that is dynamically created by SQL Server (via `SELECT INTO ...`) and then checking the properties of the columns in the newly created table:

```sql
SELECT *
INTO #CheckCollation
FROM OPENJSON(N'{}'));

SELECT [name], [system_type_id], [collation_name], [is_nullable]
FROM   tempdb.sys.columns col
WHERE  col.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#CheckCollation');

-- [key] column has collation of Latin1_General_BIN2
-- [value] column has collation of passed-in JSON value:
--     if passing in column, then collation of column, OR
--     if passing in variable or literal, then default collation of database
```

Alternatively, [@Charlieface](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/220697/charlieface) (in a comment on this answer) was kind enough to remind us that there is an easier way to get this info by using the cool built-in dynamic management function, `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set`, and provided a working example via [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/u1XyjGeX). I updated that example to include the stored procedure version of that function, `sys.sp_describe_first_result_set`, as well as the example code shown above.

Comment: `COLLATE DATABASE DEFAULT` might be wiser, in case it gets changed. Also `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` might be an easier way to find the collation of a result https://dbfiddle.uk/vZ_CWm82

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks for that feedback . Re: `DATABASE_DEFAULT`, I realize that it's a fairly popular option, but I believe it's used more often than it should be. It's truly great for operations that need to be sensitive to the environment, especially when that environment might change or if the code gets deployed to various places that don't have a guarantee of using the same collation. However, a lot of operations need to behave consistently from an app perspective, regardless of environment. Re: `dm_exec_describe_first_result_set`, I had forgotten about that, so I updated my answer.